# Regex - Delete <div>'s from text string

Tags: c#, regex

I need to remove:

```
<div class="names to-remove" style="height: 7%; font-size: 12.0074px;">
        <span style="left:37.5%">
            <span>Melle</span>
        </span>
        <span style="left:61.3%">
            <span>Andrea</span>
        </span>
    </div>
<div class="names" style="font-size: 12.0074px;"></div>
```

from:

```
<div id="dpo_base_image">
    <img src="https://cdn.shopify.com/s/files/1/0255/3187/5433/t/8/assets/NewBackground-min.jpg?v=1585826184" class="to-remove">
    <img src="https://cdn.shopify.com/s/files/1/0255/3187/5433/t/8/assets/dpo_custom_option_23627_2-1-skin-hell-min.png?v=1585173706" class="to-remove">
    <img src="https://cdn.shopify.com/s/files/1/0255/3187/5433/t/8/assets/dpo_custom_option_90934_2-1-shirt-rot.png?v=1585188911" class="to-remove">
    <img class="hairstyle to-remove" style="position:absolute; width:22.32%; top:34.9%; left:26.34%" src="https://cdn.shopify.com/s/files/1/0255/3187/5433/t/8/assets/dpo_custom_option_41253_beige.png?v=1585648292">
    <img src="https://cdn.shopify.com/s/files/1/0255/3187/5433/t/8/assets/dpo_custom_option_30683_2-2-skin-hell.png?v=1585188210" class="to-remove">
    <img src="https://cdn.shopify.com/s/files/1/0255/3187/5433/t/8/assets/dpo_custom_option_37715_2-2-shirt-gr-n.png?v=1585189163" class="to-remove">
    <img class="hairstyle to-remove" style="position:absolute; width:22.32%; top:34.9%; left:50.14%" src="https://cdn.shopify.com/s/files/1/0255/3187/5433/t/8/assets/dpo_custom_option_41253_beige.png?v=1585648292">
    <div class="names to-remove" style="height: 7%; font-size: 12.0074px;">
        <span style="left:37.5%">
            <span>Melle</span>
        </span>
        <span style="left:61.3%">
            <span>Andrea</span>
        </span>
    </div>
    <div class="names" style="font-size: 12.0074px;"></div>
</div>
```

I have tried:

```
string start = "names to-remove";
string end = "</div>";
html = Regex.Replace(html, Regex.Escape(start) + "(?<data>[^" + Regex.Escape(end) + "]*)" + Regex.Escape(end), string.Empty);
```

The result should be:

```
<div id="dpo_base_image">
    <img src="https://cdn.shopify.com/s/files/1/0255/3187/5433/t/8/assets/NewBackground-min.jpg?v=1585826184" class="to-remove">
    <img src="https://cdn.shopify.com/s/files/1/0255/3187/5433/t/8/assets/dpo_custom_option_23627_2-1-skin-hell-min.png?v=1585173706" class="to-remove">
    <img src="https://cdn.shopify.com/s/files/1/0255/3187/5433/t/8/assets/dpo_custom_option_90934_2-1-shirt-rot.png?v=1585188911" class="to-remove">
    <img class="hairstyle to-remove" style="position:absolute; width:22.32%; top:34.9%; left:26.34%" src="https://cdn.shopify.com/s/files/1/0255/3187/5433/t/8/assets/dpo_custom_option_41253_beige.png?v=1585648292">
    <img src="https://cdn.shopify.com/s/files/1/0255/3187/5433/t/8/assets/dpo_custom_option_30683_2-2-skin-hell.png?v=1585188210" class="to-remove">
    <img src="https://cdn.shopify.com/s/files/1/0255/3187/5433/t/8/assets/dpo_custom_option_37715_2-2-shirt-gr-n.png?v=1585189163" class="to-remove">
    <img class="hairstyle to-remove" style="position:absolute; width:22.32%; top:34.9%; left:50.14%" src="https://cdn.shopify.com/s/files/1/0255/3187/5433/t/8/assets/dpo_custom_option_41253_beige.png?v=1585648292">
</div>
```

Can anyone point me in the direction of the correct Regex please?

Comment: Use HtmlAgilityPack.

Comment: I wouldn't do this with Regex. Some DOM processing seems better to me for the job.

Comment: I think you should try XSLT

Answer (score 0):

Thanks to everyone for the pointer to HtmlAgilityPack.

This is my solution:

```
HtmlDocument htmlDoc = new HtmlDocument();
htmlDoc.LoadHtml(html);

HtmlNode divContainer1 = htmlDoc.DocumentNode
         .SelectSingleNode("//div[@class='names to-remove']");
divContainer1.Remove();

HtmlNode divContainer2 = htmlDoc.DocumentNode
         .SelectSingleNode("//div[@class='names']");
divContainer2.Remove();

html = htmlDoc.DocumentNode.InnerHtml;
```